# Chrome onMessage Listener not getting called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am experimenting with the `chrome.extension` API.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "First extension",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["test.js"]
    },    
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },    
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "display.js"  ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]    
    } ],

    "permissions" : [
        "tabs",
    "http://*/*", "https://*/"
        ]
}
```

**display.js**

```
alert("inside display.js");

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse){
            alert("inside msg");
            var time = request.sel_text;
            alert(time);

        });
```

**test.js**

```
function check(tab_id, data, tab){
    if(tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file" : "display.js"}) ;
    }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
```

**popup1.js**

```
function myfunc(){

    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    alert(x);
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({sel_text: x});

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#options').change(myfunc);

});
```

Now, when my page loads I get`three(3)` popups saying `inside display.js` but `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener` is never called.

So, what am I doing wrong. Can we can access `chrome.extension.*` API from content script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chrome.extension.sendMessage` only triggers `onMessage` listeners in the extension's scope, **excluding content scripts**.

You can notify content scripts using the [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage) method, as follows:

```
function myfunc() {
    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    var message = {sel_text: x};
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tabId = tabs[0].id;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Can you provide me the documentation where it is stated that `chrome.extension.sendMessage ` doesn't triggers for content script because I am founding the chrome message API highly confusing.

Comment: "Note that extensions cannot send messages to content scripts using this method. To send messages to content scripts, use chrome.tabs.sendMessage()." - docs for [`chrome.extension.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage) (and experience).

Comment: (previous comment rescinded)  It does. I incorrectly read the docs and figured out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.extension.sendMessage({sel_text: x});` which is in `popup1.js` not used or referenced in your manifest file. Where are you using `popup1.js` in your extension?

[chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage) is fired  when a message is sent from either an extension process or a content script, you don't have any messages being sent in your code!.

Moreover, why do you want re-inject script `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file" : "display.js"}) ;` from `background page` while it is already registered with `manifest file`.

Comment: `popup1.js` is used in `popup.html` [file](http://sprunge.us/ITDJ). I am using `sendMessage` in popup1.js so I believe I am sending a message.

Comment: @Noob: Message is only sent when only `browser action icon` is clicked or `popup.html` is activated, have you tried it?

Comment: When it seems working fine? After you click your `browser action icon`?It seems you are merging `content scripts` code with `background code`, what is you want to achieve?

Comment: It works fine after clicking page_action icon. What I want to achieve is using the value selected from the dropdown(sel_text) I want to perform some DOM manipulation. So I passed that value using `sendMessage` and I am trying to collect it inside my `content script(display.js)` where I will do all the DOM manipulation.

Comment: If you want to send messages to content script, send it by using a `tabId` Which you get using `tabs.query() API` instead of reverting to default(In your current code `chrome.extension.sendMessage({sel_text: x});` .